# What's the easiest way to move from Linux Mint 13 to 14?

Tags: linux-mint

I want to switch to 14 as easily as possible.  What's the best way?  Do I have to remove 13 and install 14 from scratch, or is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

As bahamat said, Mint is Debian derived, so you should

1. update your `sources.list`:

   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
2. Change `maya` to `nadia` and `precise` to `quantal`:

Paste this into sources.list:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ nadia main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ quantal partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ quantal free non-free
#deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb apps
#deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb games
```

3. Update packages:

   sudo apt-get update
4. Update and upgrade distribution:

   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get upgrade
5. To clean up

   sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo apt-get autoremove
6. Reboot

   sudo reboot
7. After rebooting select desired desktop environment.

Comment: and if you want to upgrade to LM15, use `olivia` instead of nadia, and `raring` instead of quantal

Answer (score 2):

Because Mint is Debian derived, the easiest way is to update your `sources.list` to use the new version of the repositories, then use apt-get (or aptitude) to install debconf and apt-get (and/or aptitude). Then dist-upgrade.

Not being a Mint user myself, I don't know what the correct `sources.list` should be (and 5 seconds on Google didn't reveal it) and I've obviously not tested this. But being a long time Debian user this is reasonably likely to be safe. Even still, test this yourself before actually doing it and have a back up of your data.